# Bind jQuery function to custom event listener

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery code which is fired on click. But I need it to be fired with custom `inview` event (provided by [jquery.inview](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview) library).

The code (which is fired on click):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var split = $("[class^='splitText'],[class*=' splitText']").splitText({ // animation options go here });
$("#letters").on('click',function(){
    split.animate();
});
$("#words").on('click',function(){
    split.animate();
});
$("#lines").on('click',function(){
    split.animate();
});
$("#reverse").on('click',function(){
    split.reverse();
});
$("#type").on('change',function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var opts = { // another animation options go here };
    
    if(value == 'lines'){
        opts.animation = 'slide';
    }
    split = $("[class^='splitText'],[class*=' splitText']").splitText(opts);
});
});
```

I tried to do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var split = $("[class^='splitText'],[class*=' splitText']").splitText({ // animation options go here });
$("[class^='splitText'],[class*=' splitText']").on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
  if (isInView) {
    // element is now visible in the viewport
    split.animate();
  } else {
    // element has gone out of viewport
    split.reverse();
  }
});
});
```

But it doesn't work.

What am I missing, how do I fire the code on `inview` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for attention and time being spent here, I've found a solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var split = $("[class^='splitText'],[class*=' splitText']");
var opts = {'type':'letters','animation':'explode','useLite':true};

$("[class^='splitText'],[class*=' splitText']").each(function(){
$(this).on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
if (isInView) { $(this).splitText(opts).animate(); }
else { $(this).splitText(opts).reverse(); }
    });
  });
});
```